# Using Cassandra InstantCodec

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

Trying to write and read *timestamp* column in Cassandra. Registered *InstantCodec* to convert Java *Instant* into Cassandra timestamp and vice versa.

Now when I insert the Instant using below query its is saved in this format "***2018-07-18 22:16:00.056000+0000***" instead of usual Instant toString() format "***2018-07-18T22:16:00.056Z***".

```
insert = connector_.getSession().prepare(insertInto("keyspaceName", "tableName").value("date1", bindMarker())
```

So when I read the row using CQLSH with date column in select query it throws

```
cqlsh>select * from tableName where date1 = '2018-07-18 22:16:00.056000+0000'
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2018-07-18 22:16:00.056000+0000' to a formatted date (long)"
```

But if I query with usual format like below then it works.

```
cqlsh>select * from tableName where date1 = '2018-07-18 22:16:00.056'
date                            |
---------------------------------
2018-07-18 22:16:00.056000+0000
```

It will be better if I can save it like "**2018-07-18T22:16:00.056Z**", or be able to query in CQLSH with '**2018-07-18 22:16:00.056000+0000**' in where clause.

Answer (score 3):

First - you can insert using the standard format used by `Instant`, like `2018-07-18T22:16:00.056Z` - CQL [supports different variants of the ISO-8601 standard](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html).  You can even bind `Instant` values directly if you add [optional codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/custom_codecs/extras/).

Regarding the second thing - per documentation:

> Values for the timestamp type are encoded as 64-bit signed integers representing a number of **milliseconds** since the standard base time known as the epoch

But you're trying to specify microseconds precision, that isn't supported... (different variants with milliseconds resolution works just fine). Although I agree that it's confusing that CQLSH outputs in microseconds precision, and you can't the same data in queries...

Comment: Inserting Instant through cqlsh command line save it like 2018-07-18T22:16:00.056Z , but my problem is being able to save it in same format through java code for which I am using InstantCodec. When I use InstantCodec it saves Instant like 2018-07-18 22:16:00.056000+0000

Comment: The first link in your answer is broken I guess. If you can please it that will be great.

Comment: Sorry, replaced the link. Regarding the `Instant` - if you check it via cqlsh, then it uses date formatter that shows it by default without `T` - it's just a matter of formatting. Inside Cassandra data is stored as `long` anyway